# How long does it take to calculate one frame (parallelized on CPU and GPU) when applying box blur?

Tags: c, gpu, cpu

I'm challenged by the question how long it takes to calculate a frame (by using box blur filter) on a CPU (parallelized code) and on GPU by using opencl. Of course, it depends on the hardware, but there should be a rule of thumb I guess.

I read about how a frame is calculated when using the box blur filter. As far as I understood, every new pixel is the result of calculating the average of its 8 neighbors. But I still do not have a clue, how long it could take to calculate one frame.

Comment: The actual time definitely depends on the hardware, the algorithm, the compiler and of course the image size. But if your underlying concern is "is this worth using a GPU to do this computation?", the answer is no. Transferring the data, processing it on the GPU and getting it back will be by far longer than doing the filtering on a CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the size of the frame a lot. Box blur is a parallel operation, the calculation can be done for each pixel independently of all the other pixels. Furthermore, the algorithm is in the memory limit, meaning that not compute power but memory bandwidth is the bottleneck. In general, video memory (50-1000 GB/s) is much faster than system memory (5-80 GB/s).
If the frame already is in video memory (or system memory respectively) beforehand, you will see a speedup in the order of 10x to 100x for frames as large as or larger than 1920x1080. However, for small frames the PCIe transfer will ruin the speedup due to latency (it takes at least about 10µs).
So I would guess for 1920x1080 pixels the CPU time would be in the order of 1/10s and the GPU time in the order of 1/500s.